# How to position widget according to other widget's preferred size?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, widgets need to be placed relative to each other. One widget's position is determined by other widgets' preferred widths and heights.

How am I to access one widget's preferred dimensions while building the other widgets?

Example:

[image: screenshot]

In this example

- "2" widget's top is aligned to "1" widgets height.
- "2" widget's left is aligned to "1" widget's width.
- "3" widget's top is aligned to sum of "1" widget and "2" widgets' height.

Comment: check `CustomMultiChildLayout`